# Entity Framework Core apply migrations programmatically

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have test and live db. For test db migrations I use `Add-Migration ...` and `Update-Database` syntax in package manager console. But for live db I want to do it programmatically when app is started.

The following code didn't help me:

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```

I have error `Invalid object name 'TempTenants'` when I try to add record to table that doesn't exist. This is my new table.

But I have `_EFMigrationsHistory` table. And there are all my migrations even those that weren't applied. But I don't see new table.

I will have the same result if I manually remove table from test db and try to reproduce error.

So, `context.Database.Migrate();` only create new db with all migrations, if it doesn't exist, but don't update (apply migrations) existing db.

Can I do that? And how can I resolve that?

Comment: Please be more clear on "it didn't help me". Why? What happened? Error message? Also was your db initially also created by migrations (is there a `__EFMigrationsHistory` table)?

Comment: @Tseng I've updated my question, look at it, please.

Comment: No exceptions during start? What do the logs read? Does the user have sufficient write permissions on the database server? (ALTER / CREATE statements)

Comment: "I have error" - yes, but which error?

Comment: No exceptions during start, user has permissions.

Comment: @ErikEJ Updated question

Comment: using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems something went wrong. I removed unapplied migrations (records) from `__EFMigrationsHistory` table (also I needed to revert some table names, primary and foreign keys to previous state) and launched app again.

So, `context.Database.Migrate();` apply migrations even for existing databases.

Comment: I am facing exactly same problem, while running `Add-Migration` command. It triggers the `configure` method in `Startup.cs` class which has `context.Database.Migrate()`. After this line I am seeding data to Database and I'm getting same Error message as `Invalid Object Name`.

Comment: Where on the `Startup.cs` file do you place  `context.Database.Migrate()`

Comment: @SwalehMatongwa at the end of `Configure` method